# jQuery: Change position from fixed to relative if div is higher than 90vh

Tags: jquery

I would like to have a fixed contact field (`#contact`) on the bottom of a website. But, if the text area (`#text`) is higher than `90vh`, the `position: fixed` should change to a `position: relative`.

That's how I started:

```js
function contactPosition() {
  $("#text").height(higherThan90vh);
  $("#contact").css("position", "relative");
}

$(window).on("load resize", contactPosition).resize();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#contact {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<div id="contact">mail@mail.com</div>
```

I have no idea how to continue, and would be very thankful for help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the meaning of [vh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units):

> vh    1% of the viewport's height.

you can convert the text height in vh and compare with 90vh:

```js
// convert px to vh: height retuns a measure in px
function pxTOvh(value) {
    var w = window,
            d = document,
            e = d.documentElement,
            g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
            y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;

    var result = (100 * value) / y;
    return result;
}
function contactPosition() {
    if (pxTOvh($("#text").height()) >= 90)
        $("#contact").css("position", "relative");
    else
        $("#contact").css("position", "fixed");
}

$(window).on("load resize", contactPosition).resize();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#contact {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
    et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
    duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>

<div id="contact">mail@mail.com</div>
```